# Angular 7+: HMR (Hot Module Replacement) does not work if any route-resolve involved

Tags: angular, routes, resolve, webpack-hmr, hot-module-replacement

HMR (Hot Module Replacement) is a great functionality, that works properly if no "Route-resolve" (see below) is present.

If I remove `resolve` here:

```
  {
    path: 'new',
    component: BookNewComponent,
    data: {
      breadcrumb: 'book.new.breadcrumb'
    },
    resolve: {
      staticData: StaticDataResolve
    }
  },
```

HMR is working again. If `resolve` exists -> HMR reloads the whole app instead of a specific component.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How looks like your Resolve service?

Comment: Subscribing HttpClient

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48236160/angular-cli-hmr-with-lazy-loaded-routes-hot-reloads-the-whole-thing